# PHP array_slice OR array_pop not del?

Tags: php, slice

the php Function array_slice OR array_pop not Work ?

```
object(stdClass)#2 (9) {
  ["colVorname"]=>
  string(3) "vor"
  ["colNachname"]=>
  string(4) "nach"
  ["colGeb"]=>
  string(10) "01.02.2014"
  ["colStrasse"]=>
  string(3) "str"
  ["colPlz"]=>
  string(3) "123"
  ["colStadt"]=>
  string(5) "stadt"
  ["colEmail"]=>
  string(9) "e@mail.de"
  ["colPasswort"]=>
  string(4) "pass"
  ["colPasswortw"]=>
  string(4) "pass"
}
```

`array_slice($submit, 0, -1) OR array_pop($submit)` not del **colPasswortw** why?:

Comment: It's not an array, to begin with. If you get it from JSON, use `json_decode($source_str, true)` to convert the source into an associative array instead. As it stands, you can just `unset($submit->colPasswortw)` to remove that property.

Comment: This woks, thanks :o)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it's `object` not `array` and `array_slice` and `array_pop` both are array manipulation function, so you should convert `object` in `array`, see below

```
$submit = (array) $assoc_object; 

//and now you can use $submit with functions

array_slice($submit, 0, -1)
```

Answer (score 0):

You are dealing with php object instead of array an easy way is convert it to array and then apply function and my suggestion is

**Required function:**

[json_encode](http://php.net/json_encode)

[json_decode](http://php.net/json_encode)

***SAMPLE:***

```
<?php
     $jsonedObject = json_encode($yourObject);
     $resultantArray = json_decode($jsonedObject, TRUE);
     print_r($resultantArray);
?>
```